# How to copy the head of files into some other files without losing linebreaks in bash?

Tags: bash, echo, head

What I've got is something like this:

```
working_dir
|-- samples
|-- table1.tbl
|-- table2.tbl
|-- table3.tbl
```

What I want to have is something like this:

```
working_dir
|-- samples
|   |-- table1.tbl
|   |-- table2.tbl
|   |-- table3.tbl
|-- table1.tbl
|-- table2.tbl
|-- table3.tbl
```

And the .tbl files in the `samples` directory will contain the first 10 lines of those .tbl files in the root directory.

I've tried

```
for FILE in `ls *.tbl`; do
  NEWFILE="samples/$FILE"
  if [ ! -f "$NEWFILE" ] ; then
      touch "$NEWFILE"
  fi
  echo `head $FILE` > $NEWFILE
done
```

but the linebreaks in the .tbl files under `samples` were lost, the content of the 10 lines are squeezed into one line in each .tbl file.

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for FILE in *.tbl; do
  head "$FILE" > "samples/$FILE"
done
```

Your problem was caused by the echo and the backticks. The backticks flatten the output into one line and echo simply outputs that single line.

Comment: It's not the backticks that flatten. Using echo without quoting is the culprit. This would have worked: `echo "$(head "$file")"`, but needlessly complex.

Comment: Backquotes *without double-quotes around them* turn all whitespace (spaces, tabs, linefeeds, whatever) into word breaks; `echo` then turns all word breaks into spaces. BTW, michas' version also fixes a similar potential problem with whitespace in filenames by simply removing the backquoted-`ls` thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=/path/to/file
find /absolute/path/to/dir -name "*.tbl" > /path/to/file

for FILE in $(cat /path/to/file); do
    head "$FILE" > "/path/to/sample/$FILE"
done
```